# How to determine current clipboard DataFlavor before get clip content

Tags: java, groovy

I have following trouble, when i copy Intellij Idea Editor text, and run

```
Toolkit.defaultToolkit.systemClipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)
```

it will raise:

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
```

In fact, I hope ignore clip content with FoldingData, how to detect current clipboard DataFlavor

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard data may be available in multiple flavors. Therefore, you should use Clipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors() and iterate through the array to determine if the DataFlavor you are looking for is there.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html#getAvailableDataFlavors()

But if you are getting a `ClassNotFoundException`, this means that your runtime classpath is missing dependencies, so you need to fix this

Comment: the question is ClassNotFoundException is not exception, it's warning, i cannot capture it

Answer (score 0):

This way you can check the **DataFlavor** earlier to avoid the **UnsupportedFlavorException** later

```
public class ClipBoard { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null); 
        try { 
            if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) { 
                String text = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 
                text=text.toUpperCase(); 
                StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(text); 
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null); 
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Read more: http://mrbool.com/manipulating-clipboard-content-with-java/24758#ixzz4tta4bwNQ